# How to save / export a XPlot Plotly or Google Chart to PDF / image (F#)?

Tags: f#, google-visualization, export, plotly

when I create a chart in XPlot (F#) with Plotly (or Google Charts) like this

```
let trace =
    Scatter(
        x = [1; 2; 3; 4],
        y = [10; 15; 13; 17]
    )
let chart = Chart.Plot trace
Chart.Show chart
```

How can I export the chart as PDF or image file?

Thanks very much!

**Update:**

I can get the HTML string and export it as follows

```
let chartHtml = chart.GetHtml()
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:/temp/chart.html", chartHtml)
```

Next I need to figure out how to transform the HTML into a PNG or a PDF. Any ideas?

**2nd update:**

I tried using several HTML-to-PDF converter libraries, including

- [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf/)
- [Select.HtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/) (see suggestion by @Jeff_hk below)

Unfortunately, those don't do the job. I guess that the support for JavaScript is limited. The HTML output from XPlot imports the Plotly library (JS).

For now I'm using [FSharp.Charting](https://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/) that comes with its own export methods, but is less versatile.

Any other suggestions are still welcome! Thanks

Comment: for google charts, use the [`getImageURI` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)

Comment: @WhiteHat: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, the `getImageURI` method does not seem to be provided through the XPlot API.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already the html saved somewhere, you can just then use the package (on NuGet) **Select.HtmlToPdf**

Here an example

```
let conv = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf()
let doc = conv.ConvertUrl("d:/index.html")
doc.Save("d:/index.pdf")
doc.Close()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @lukasimir did it help?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the following exception:
`System.Exception: Conversion error: Navigation timeout.
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToImage.ᜀ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, ᥻[]& A_3, ᣰ& A_4)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(String htmlString)`
It also didn't work with other HTML converters, see update in original question. Thanks anyway!